# datagrid get cell index

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

Does it possible to get cell index where column header = "column4" and row contains "232"
for example i uploaded screen shot does it possible to get red cell index and than make it color red? and if wpf datagrid have that function does wpf toolkit data grid has? columns and rows are adding from code behind[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should be doing this through `Style`/`Trigger` or `Binding` with a converter like

```
<DataGrid Name="dataGrid"
          ...>
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="column4" Binding="{Binding column4}">
            <DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
                <Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding column4}" Value="232">
                            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"/>
                        </DataTrigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
        </DataGridTextColumn>
        <!--...-->
    </DataGrid.Columns>
    <!--...-->
</DataGrid>
```

---

By default, the `DataGrid` is using virtualization so only the `DataGridRows` that are visible to the user at the moment will be loaded. The other rows will be created once they become visible so if you're trying to style some cells in code behind in can become pretty messy (the cell you are trying to access might not even exist yet.)

To get a `DataGridCell` at index row/column you can define a helper class (`DataGridHelper`) and use it like this

```
DataGridCell cell = DataGridHelper.GetCell(dataGrid, 0, 2);
if (cell != null)
{
    cell.Background = Brushes.Red;
}
```

**DataGridHelper**

```
static class DataGridHelper
{
    static public DataGridCell GetCell(DataGrid dg, int row, int column)
    {
        DataGridRow rowContainer = GetRow(dg, row);

        if (rowContainer != null)
        {
            DataGridCellsPresenter presenter = GetVisualChild<DataGridCellsPresenter>(rowContainer);

            // try to get the cell but it may possibly be virtualized
            DataGridCell cell = (DataGridCell)presenter.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(column);
            if (cell == null)
            {
                // now try to bring into view and retreive the cell
                dg.ScrollIntoView(rowContainer, dg.Columns[column]);
                cell = (DataGridCell)presenter.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(column);
            }
            return cell;
        }
        return null;
    }

    static public DataGridRow GetRow(DataGrid dg, int index)
    {
        DataGridRow row = (DataGridRow)dg.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(index);
        if (row == null)
        {
            // may be virtualized, bring into view and try again
            dg.ScrollIntoView(dg.Items[index]);
            row = (DataGridRow)dg.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(index);
        }
        return row;
    }

    static T GetVisualChild<T>(Visual parent) where T : Visual
    {
        T child = default(T);
        int numVisuals = VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(parent);
        for (int i = 0; i < numVisuals; i++)
        {
            Visual v = (Visual)VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(parent, i);
            child = v as T;
            if (child == null)
            {
                child = GetVisualChild<T>(v);
            }
            if (child != null)
            {
                break;
            }
        }
        return child;
    }
}
```