# Select multiple items from a DataGrid in an MVVM WPF project

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, datagrid

How can I select multiple items from a `DataGrid` in an MVVM WPF project?

Answer (score 119, accepted):

You can simply add a *custom dependency property* to do this:

```
public class CustomDataGrid : DataGrid
{
    public CustomDataGrid ()
    {
        this.SelectionChanged += CustomDataGrid_SelectionChanged;
    }

    void CustomDataGrid_SelectionChanged (object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.SelectedItemsList = this.SelectedItems;
    }
    #region SelectedItemsList

    public IList SelectedItemsList
    {
        get { return (IList)GetValue (SelectedItemsListProperty); }
        set { SetValue (SelectedItemsListProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty SelectedItemsListProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register ("SelectedItemsList", typeof (IList), typeof (CustomDataGrid), new PropertyMetadata (null));

    #endregion
}
```

Now you can use this `dataGrid` in the XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="DataGridTesting.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:DataGridTesting.CustomDatagrid"
    Title="MainWindow"
    Height="350"
    Width="525">
  <DockPanel>
    <local:CustomDataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Model}"
        SelectionMode="Extended"
        AlternatingRowBackground="Aquamarine"
        SelectionUnit="FullRow"
        IsReadOnly="True"
        SnapsToDevicePixels="True"
        SelectedItemsList="{Binding TestSelected, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
  </DockPanel>
</Window>
```

My `ViewModel`:

```
public class MyViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private static object _lock = new object ();
    private List<MyModel> _myModel;

    public IEnumerable<MyModel> Model { get { return _myModel; } }

    private IList _selectedModels = new ArrayList ();

    public IList TestSelected
    {
        get { return _selectedModels; }
        set
        {
            _selectedModels = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged ("TestSelected");
        }
    }

    public MyViewModel ()
    {
        _myModel = new List<MyModel> ();
        BindingOperations.EnableCollectionSynchronization (_myModel, _lock);

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            _myModel.Add (new MyModel
            {
                Name = "Test " + i,
                Age = i * 22
            });
        }
        RaisePropertyChanged ("Model");
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public void RaisePropertyChanged (string propertyName)
    {
        var pc = PropertyChanged;
        if (pc != null)
            pc (this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs (propertyName));
    }
}
```

My model:

```
public class MyModel
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
}
```

And finally, here is the code behind of `MainWindow`:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow ()
    {
        InitializeComponent ();
        this.DataContext = new MyViewModel ();
    }
}
```

I hope this clean MVVM design helps.

Comment: I tried your code and it works fine when it is selecting the multiple rows but when I implement a delete function, it causes an exception. can you please see this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29675086/collection-was-modified-when-trying-to-remove-selected-items-of-datagrid

Comment: Looks like you got your answer :)

Comment: This would not work if you want to check if the new selected items list equals the previous in your setter of TestSelected. The reason is that both SelectedItemsList and SelectedItemseason in CustomDataGrid_SelectionChanged contain the same reference to the list. So they will always be equal.

Comment: @tabina You are right that this solution is useful only when you want to get all the __currently__ selected items and is of no use if you want to compare it with old selected items. What you can do is modify the `PropertyMetadata` of the Dependency Property to include a function which can do the comparison

Comment: I've made an attached property `local:SelectedItems` so I do not need to subclass the `DataGrid`.

Comment: `this.SelectedItemsList = this.SelectedItems;` did not work for me, as `SelectedItemsList` was always set to `null`. However, changing the code to `foreach (var item in this.SelectedItems) { this.SelectedItemsList.Add(item); }` did the trick. Please note, that this requires you to call `this.SelectedItemsList.Clear();` in advance, so the items of `SelectedItemsList` will not get duplicated.

Comment: Why do u have TwoWay binding of SelectedItemsList? I dont think your code can handle changing the SelectedItems property from its Source (VM).

Comment: is there a way to bind it to a typed list? so instead of IList SelectedModel bind to a property of type List<MyModel>

Comment: @sjorsmiltenburg  just do it like M463 suggested, add the items to the existing list, then it also works with typed lists.

Comment: Why `TwoWay` if you cannot set the Grid's `SelectedItems`?

Answer (score 30):

What I would do is create `Behaviors` using `System.Windows.Interactivity`. You would have to reference it manually in your project.

Given a control which doesn't expose `SelectedItems` e.g., (ListBox, DataGrid)

You can create a behavior class something like this

```
public class ListBoxSelectedItemsBehavior : Behavior<ListBox>
{
    protected override void OnAttached()
    {
        AssociatedObject.SelectionChanged += AssociatedObjectSelectionChanged;
    }

    protected override void OnDetaching()
    {
        AssociatedObject.SelectionChanged -= AssociatedObjectSelectionChanged;
    }

    void AssociatedObjectSelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var array = new object[AssociatedObject.SelectedItems.Count];
        AssociatedObject.SelectedItems.CopyTo(array, 0);
        SelectedItems = array;
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty SelectedItemsProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("SelectedItems", typeof(IEnumerable), typeof(ListBoxSelectedItemsBehavior), 
        new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(null, FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.BindsTwoWayByDefault));

    public IEnumerable SelectedItems
    {
        get { return (IEnumerable)GetValue(SelectedItemsProperty); }
        set { SetValue(SelectedItemsProperty, value); }
    }
}
```

And on your `XAML` I would do the `Binding` like this where `i` is `xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity"` and `behaviors` is the namespace of your `Behavior` class

```
<ListBox>
 <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
    <behaviors:ListBoxSelectedItemsBehavior SelectedItems="{Binding SelectedItems, Mode=OneWayToSource}" />
 </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
```

Assuming that your `DataContext` for the `ListBox` has the `SelectedItems` property in the `ViewModel` then it will automatically update the `SelectedItems`. You have encapsulated the `event` subscribing from the `View` i.e.,

```
<ListBox SelectionChanged="ListBox_SelectionChanged"/>
```

You can change the `Behavior` class to be of type `DataGrid` if you want.

Comment: @III What is the purpose of <ListBox SelectionChanged="ListBox_SelectionChanged> here

Comment: @MegaMind I am trying to emphasize that you won't need SelectionChanged event when you used behaviors.

Comment: @III I have tried your solution, but in view model, selected items always remains null. I have compiled a simple solution depicting your code. If you could take a look at that. https://www.dropbox.com/s/lh4zrhnatpchqzi/MultiSelectedDataGrid.zip?dl=0

Comment: If you do this with UWP use IList<object> instead of IList. Nice solution.

Comment: @Edward You are referencing the same answer?

Comment: @III - Yes, silly me, I referenced the same answer. I can't edit my bad comment now so I've deleted it - THIS was the one that worked for me: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8088926 . As I said in my old comment (now deleted), your answer didn't work for me, SelectedItems is always null, like for MegaMind. The other answer is almost the same as yours, and it works for me.

Comment: `DataGrid` HAS a `SelectedItems` property, but it's not a dependency property so binding does not work. > doesn't expose `SelectedItems` is a wrong statement.

Comment: As long as `SelectedItems` is of type `IEnumerable` I also got `null`. But as soon as the type was changed to `IList` the data came. Unfortunately the Binding was not really TwoWay. The solution was a combination between this answer and this [blog entry](https://www.tyrrrz.me/Blog/WPF-ListBox-SelectedItems-TwoWay-binding)

Comment: Just repeating @RaphaelMüller comment above: for actually working `TwoWay` binding you can use the solution from [WPF ListBox SelectedItems TwoWay Binding](https://tyrrrz.me/blog/wpf-listbox-selecteditems-twoway-binding). I've just copied and it worked, not combined anything at all in my case.

Answer (score 23):

I use this solution in my app:

XAML:

```
<i:Interaction.Triggers>
     <i:EventTrigger EventName="SelectionChanged">
         <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding SelectItemsCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding Path=SelectedItems,ElementName=TestListView}"/>
     </i:EventTrigger>
</i:Interaction.Triggers>
```

at the top of you xaml file, add this line of code:

```
xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity"
```

SelectedItemsCommand is ICommand type which is written in your viewmodel.

Used DLL:

System.Windows.Interactivity.dll

Answer (score 12):

With the default `DataGrid` of WPF it is not possible to use a Binding, as it is possible with the `SelectedItem`-Property, cause the `SelectedItems`-Property is not a DependencyProperty.

One way to to what you want is to register the `SelectionChanged`-Event of the DataGrid to update the property of your ViewModel, that stores the selected items.

The property [SelectedItems](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.multiselector.selecteditems%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) of the DataGrid is of type IList so you need to cast the items in the list to your specific type.

C#

```
public MyViewModel {
  get{
    return this.DataContext as MyViewModel;
  }
}

private void DataGrid_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e) {
  // ... Get SelectedItems from DataGrid.
  var grid = sender as DataGrid;
  var selected = grid.SelectedItems;

  List<MyObject> selectedObjects = selected.OfType<MyObject>().ToList();

  MyViewModel.SelectedMyObjects = selectedObjects;
}
```

XAML

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
    <DataGrid
        SelectionChanged="DataGrid_SelectionChanged"
        />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I am looking for something pure MVVM based and that should not involved code behind

Comment: I appreciate this answer. Even though it's not MVVM it's the first one to mention _why_ I can't access the `SelectedItems` property in XAML.

Comment: And it doesn't corrupt your MVVM model at all. You still have a pure SelectedMyObjects property in your VM that knows nothing about the View or how it gets set. Just having some code in the View doesn't mean it's not pure MVVM.

Answer (score 2):

You can add the "IsSelected" property in the Model and add a checkBox in the row.

Answer (score 2):

You can maka a **reusable generic base class**. This way you can select rows **both from code and UI**.

This is my example class i want to be selectable

```
public class MyClass
{
    public string MyString {get; set;}   
}
```

Make generic base class for selectable classes. INotifyPropertyChanged makes the UI update when you set IsSelected.

```
public class SelectableItem<T> : System.ComponentModel.INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public SelectableItem(T item)
    {
        Item = item;
    }

    public T Item { get; set; }

    bool _isSelected;

    public bool IsSelected {
        get {
            return _isSelected;
        }
        set {
            if (value == _isSelected)
            {
                return;
            }

            _isSelected = value;

            if (PropertyChanged != null)
            { 
                PropertyChanged(this, new System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs("IsSelected"));
            }
        }
    }

    public event System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
}
```

Create selectable class

```
public class MySelectableItem: SelectableItem<MyClass>
{
    public MySelectableItem(MyClass item)
       :base(item)
    {
    }
}
```

Create property to bind to

```
ObservableCollection<MySelectableItem> MyObservableCollection ...
```

Set propety

```
MyObservableCollection = myItems.Select(x => new MySelectableItem(x));
```

Bind to datagrid and add a style on the DataGridRow that binds to the IsSelected propety on the MySelectedItem

```
<DataGrid  
    ItemsSource="{Binding MyObservableCollection}"
    SelectionMode="Extended">
    <DataGrid.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="DataGridRow">
            <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding IsSelected}" />
        </Style>
    </DataGrid.Resources>
</DataGrid>
```

To get selected rows/items

```
var selectedItems = MyObservableCollection.Where(x=>x.IsSelected).Select(y=>y.Item);
```

To select rows/items

```
MyObservableCollection[0].IsSelected = true;
```

Edit———>
It seems like it does not work when EnableRowVirtualization is true

Comment: Unfortunately, this did not work reliably for me when rows that are currently not visible (because they are scrolled out of view) get selected or deselected.

Comment: It seems like it does not work when EnableRowVirtualization is true

Answer (score 1):

My solution is almost a same like Sandesh. On the other hand, I did not use CustomDataGrid to solve this problem. Instead of that I used a plus button click event with the proper function in a viewmodel. In my code, the main point was that to be able to delete more than one person object from the Datagrid wich was bind to the PeopleList property (ObservableCollection)

**This is my Model:**

```
 public class Person
    {
        public Person()
        {

        }

        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public int Age { get; set; }

    }
}
```

**This is my ViewModel (only thoose parts, which are necessary)**:

```
public class PersonViewModel : BindableBase
    {
        private ObservableCollection<Person> _peopleList;
        // to be able to delete or save more than one person object
        private List<Person> _selectedPersonList;

        //MyICommand
        public MyICommand AddCommand { get; set; }
        public MyICommand DeleteCommand { get; set; }

        private string _firstName;
        private string _lastName;
        private int _age;

        public PersonViewModel()
        {
            _peopleList = new ObservableCollection<Person>();
            LoadPerson();
            AddCommand = new MyICommand(AddPerson);
            DeleteCommand = new MyICommand(DeletePerson, CanDeletePerson);
            // To be able to delete or save more than one person
            _selectedPersonList = new List<Person>();
        } 
public ObservableCollection<Person> PeopleList
        {
            get { return _peopleList; }
            set
            {
                _peopleList = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("PeopleList");
            }
        }
 public List<Person> SelectedPersonList
        {
            get { return _selectedPersonList; }
            set
            {
                if (_selectedPersonList != value)
                {
                    RaisePropertyChanged("SelectedPersonList");
                }
            }
        }
 private void DeletePerson()
        {
            // to be able to delete more than one person object
            foreach (Person person in SelectedPersonList)
            {
                PeopleList.Remove(person);
            }
            MessageBox.Show(""+SelectedPersonList.Count); // it is only a checking
            SelectedPersonList.Clear(); // it is a temp list, so it has to be cleared after the button push
        }
 public void GetSelectedPerson(DataGrid datagrid)
        {

            IList selectedItems = datagrid.SelectedItems;
            foreach (Person item in selectedItems)
            {
                SelectedPersonList.Add(item);
            }
        }
```

**My View (xmal):**

```
<UserControl x:Class="DataBase.Views.PersonView"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:DataBase.Views"
             xmlns:viewModel="clr-namespace:DataBase.ViewModels" d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance Type=viewModel:PersonViewModel}"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="450" d:DesignWidth="800">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Grid.RowSpan="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Background="AliceBlue">
            <TextBlock Text="First Name:"/>
            <TextBox x:Name="firstNameTxtBox" Text="{Binding FirstName, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
            <TextBlock Text="Last Name:"/>
            <TextBox x:Name="lastNameTxtBox" Text="{Binding LastName, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
            <TextBlock Text="Age:"/>
            <TextBox x:Name="ageTxtBox" Text="{Binding Age}"/>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding FullName}"/>
            <Button Content="Add" IsEnabled="{Binding CanAddPerson}" Command="{Binding AddCommand}"/>
            <Button Content="Delete" Command="{Binding DeleteCommand}" Click="Delete_Click"/>
            <DataGrid x:Name="datagridPeopleList" ItemsSource="{Binding PeopleList}" AutoGenerateColumns="True" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedPerson}" SelectionMode="Extended" SelectionUnit="FullRow"/>
            <!--<ListView Height="50" ItemsSource="{Binding PeopleList}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedPerson}" Margin="10">
            </ListView>-->
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

**My View (.cs):**

```
 public partial class PersonView : UserControl
    {
        public PersonViewModel pvm;
        public PersonView()
        {
            pvm = new PersonViewModel();
            InitializeComponent();
            DataContext = pvm;
        }

        private void Delete_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            pvm.GetSelectedPerson(datagridPeopleList);
        }
    }
```

I hope that it is useful and not the worst (non elegant) solution in the world :D

Answer (score 0):

WPF DataGrid allows for this.
Simply set the DataGrid.Rows.SelectionMode and DataGrid.Rows.SelectionUnit to "Extended" and "CellOrRowHeader" respectively. This can be done in Blend, as shown in the image I have included. This will allow user to select each cell, whole rows etc. as many as they like, using either shift or ctrl key to continue selecting.
[image]

Comment: the problem is that you won't be able to access the selected data in a MVVM project.

Answer (score 0):

The project I'm working on uses [MVVM Light](https://github.com/lbugnion/mvvmlight) and I found [this blog
post](http://blog.galasoft.ch/posts/2010/05/handling-datagrid-selecteditems-in-an-mvvm-friendly-manner/) to be the simplest solution. I'll repeat the solution here:

View Model:

```
using GalaSoft.MvvmLight;
using GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Command;
...

public class SomeVm : ViewModelBase {

    public SomeVm() {
        SelectItemsCommand = new RelayCommand<IList>((items) => {
            Selected.Clear();
            foreach (var item in items) Selected.Add((SomeClass)item);
        });

        ViewCommand = new RelayCommand(() => {
            foreach (var selected in Selected) {
                // todo do something with selected items
            }
        });
    }

    public List<SomeClass> Selected { get; set; }
    public RelayCommand<IList> SelectionChangedCommand { get; set; }
    public RelayCommand ViewCommand { get; set; }
}
```

XAML:

```
<Window
    ...
    xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity"
    xmlns:command="http://www.galasoft.ch/mvvmlight"
    ...
    <DataGrid
        Name="SomeGrid"
        ...
        <i:Interaction.Triggers>
            <i:EventTrigger EventName="SelectionChanged">
                <command:EventToCommand
                    Command="{Binding SelectionChangedCommand}"
                    CommandParameter="{Binding SelectedItems, ElementName=SomeGrid}" />
            </i:EventTrigger>
        </i:Interaction.Triggers>
        ...
        <DataGrid.ContextMenu>
            <ContextMenu>
                <MenuItem Header="View" Command="{Binding ViewCommand}" />
            </ContextMenu>
        </DataGrid.ContextMenu>
        ...
```

Comment: Your code is confusing because in the VM your Command is called SelectionChangedCommand when it's initialised but SelectItemsCommand when it's declared.