# How to identify the list of files that are selected in a datagrid wpf?

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I have a datagrid which has list of files. 
To allow multi-select , i have chosen SelectionMode="Extended".
I can use Ctrl or Shift keys to select mutliple files.

How to identify the list of files that are selected?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this to get the selected items from a datagrid.

```
List<FilesData> filesList;
for (int i = 0; i < dataGridName.SelectedItems.Count; i++)
{
    filesList.Add((FilesData)dataGridName.SelectedItems[i]);
}
```

Comment: `var filesList = dataGridName.SelectedItems.Cast<FilesData>()`

Comment: Thanks ViVi. how to achieve the same through MVVM.

Comment: You could create a Public property which is a Object[] Variable, then bind the SelectedItems to it.

<DataGrid SelectedItems="{Binding Variable}" />

Comment: **@H.B. :** Appreciate it. Never thought of writing it in 1 line. 
**@SimplyStupid:** Welcome. As @Ben Steele suggested, just create a **SelectedFilesList** property in ViewModel(ensure it implements the **INotifyPropertyChanged** interface) and bind the SelectedItems of datagrid to the property as **{Binding SelectedFilesList}**

Comment: Thank you Ben Steele. 
Thank you ViVi

Comment: @Ben Steele n ViVi:, If I am right, there is no SelectedItems property for Datagrid. I can only find SelectedItem property (correct me If I am wrong). The link provided by Nebojsa Kurjakov solved my problem. If there is a better or alternative way to solve this problem, please share your answers.

Comment: Sorry I did not get what you're saying. My DataGrid is having `SelectedItems` property. I hope everyone's does too. :)

Comment: @SimplyStupid It might be that you are not using the built in DataGrid that was bundled with WPF in .net 4. It was part of the WPF Toolkit before that version of .net https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagrid(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 1):

You can check [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22868445/wpf-binding-selecteditems-in-mvvm) to see some of the implementations of binding to SelectedItems property.

Basically, there are two popular solutions. One is to derive from DataGrid and implement your own dependency property which will expose SelectedItems property, so that it can be used for data binding:

```
public class CustomDataGrid : DataGrid{

public CustomDataGrid ()
{
    this.SelectionChanged += CustomDataGrid_SelectionChanged;
}

void CustomDataGrid_SelectionChanged (object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    this.SelectedItemsList = this.SelectedItems;
}

public IList SelectedItemsList
{
    get { return (IList)GetValue (SelectedItemsListProperty); }
    set { SetValue (SelectedItemsListProperty, value); }
}

public static readonly DependencyProperty SelectedItemsListProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register ("SelectedItemsList", typeof (IList), typeof (CustomDataGrid), new PropertyMetadata (null));
}
```

Other is to use features provided in System.Windows.Interactivity.dll assembly, and either create your own behavior, or use provided triggers and invoke command when SelectionChanged event occurs:

```
<i:Interaction.Triggers>
 <i:EventTrigger EventName="SelectionChanged">
     <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding SelectItemsCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding Path=SelectedItems,ElementName=YourDataGridName}"/>
 </i:EventTrigger>
</i:Interaction.Triggers>
```

Keep in mind that in order to use this, you would have to define "i" namespace inside your xaml like this:

```
xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity"
```