# Not able to display ListView item to textbox

Tags: c#, wpf

Hi all. When ListView item is double clicked it should display the corresponding data to text box, later i will write some code to update.

```
<p>Below is listview code on my xaml file</p>  
  <ListView Margin="534,233,10,18" Name="lvCus"  MouseDoubleClick="ListViewItem_DoubleClick">
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView AllowsColumnReorder="true" ColumnHeaderToolTip="TbCus">
                <GridViewColumn Header="CusID" Width="40" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=CusID}" />
                <GridViewColumn Header="fn" Width="120" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=fn}" />
                <GridViewColumn Header="Lastname" Width="120" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=ln}" />
                <GridViewColumn Header="Dob" Width="100" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=dob}" />
                <GridViewColumn Header="Age" Width="60" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=age}" />
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
    </ListView>
```

Below is code at backend.

```
    private void ListViewItem_DoubleClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
            ListViewItem item = lvCus.SelectedItems[0];
            txtfn.Text = item.SubItems[1].Text;
            txtln.Text = item.SubItems[2].Text;
            txtdob.Text = item.SubItems[3].Text;
    }
```

I see red underline near the code lvCus.SelectedItems[0] , Error: cannot implicitly convert type 'object' to 'System.Windows.Controls.ListViewItem'. An explict conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: `lvCus.SelectedItems` is a collection of `object`. The contents are instances of whatever you populated the `ListView` with, so that will be their actual runtime type. Cast them to that type.

Comment: Thanks, i will check that @EdPlunkett

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to cast  to your type of object say **`Customer`**

```
Customer custObj = (Customer)lvCus.SelectedItems[0];
```

Then you can access the properties

```
txtfn.Text = custObj.fn;
txtln.Text = custObj.ln;
txtdob.Text = custObj.dob;
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. Let me check.

Comment: The OP should use data binding instead of casting and directly setting UI properties

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos yes right!, but he needs to completely rewrite the existing code

Comment: Guys, Yes, I am learning WPF so i did not get idea where to define Customer.

Comment: @ShivRaj you dont have to define customer! just put the object which you have bound to list view

Comment: ListViewItem cusObj = (ListViewItem)lvCus.SelectedItems[0];
txtfn.Text = cusObj.fn; >> it says doesnot contains definition for fn, there is red underline near .fn

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130536/discussion-between-shiv-raj-and-sajeetharan).

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos OP *can't* bind `ListView.SelectedItems`. Nobody can. [People do write behaviors though.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22908694/424129)