# dataGrid.SelectedItems can not be cleared after swapping two rows from program

Tags: wpf, datagrid

I have a DataGrid in WPF. I use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22868445/select-multiple-items-from-a-datagrid-in-an-mvvm-wpf-project/22973760#22973760) technique to bind SelectedItems to my VM. I created a command which swap the two selected rows of the DataGrid. (Actually I swap the Ids, update the db, and reload (ordered by id) the ObservableCollection of the DataGrid) After that I see no selection in the DataGrid but dataGrid.SelectedItems still contains the two rows. I checked this in CodeBehind. If I select a row then dataGrid.SelectedItems contains 3 elements now. I tried to clear the selection from CodeBehind without success. I tried this methods.

```
        dataGrid.UnselectAll();
        dataGrid.UnselectAllCells();
        dataGrid.SelectedCells.Clear();
        dataGrid.SelectedItem = null;
        dataGrid.IsEnabled = false;
        dataGrid.IsEnabled = true;
        Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.Background, new Action(() => dataGrid.Items.Refresh()));
```

If I select two rows and try to unselect before swapping the rows then UnselectAll() works perfectly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, the solution was not how to unselect the rows but when to do it. It worked perfectly before swapping the rows. I could do it from ViewModel.

```
Pager.SelectedRow = null;
```

where SelectedRow is bound to DataGrid.SelectedItem.