# Custom WPF DataGrid to select one or multiple rows manually from ViewModel

Tags: wpf, mvvm, datagrid, viewmodel

I try to create a DataGrid for WPF / MVVM which allows to manually select one ore more items from ViewModel code.

As usual the DataGrid should be able to bind its ItemsSource to a List / ObservableCollection. The new part is that it should maintain another bindable list, the SelectedItemsList. Each item added to this list should immediately be selected in the DataGrid.

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22868445/select-multiple-items-from-a-datagrid-in-an-mvvm-wpf-project) solution on Stackoverflow: There the DataGrid is extended to hold a Property / DependencyProperty for the SelectedItemsList:

```
public class CustomDataGrid : DataGrid
{
  public CustomDataGrid()
  {
    this.SelectionChanged += CustomDataGrid_SelectionChanged;
  }

  private void CustomDataGrid_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
  {
    this.SelectedItemsList = this.SelectedItems;
  }

  public IList SelectedItemsList
  {
    get { return (IList)GetValue(SelectedItemsListProperty); }
    set { SetValue(SelectedItemsListProperty, value); }
  }

  public static readonly DependencyProperty SelectedItemsListProperty =
      DependencyProperty.Register("SelectedItemsList", 
                                  typeof(IList), 
                                  typeof(CustomDataGrid), 
                                  new PropertyMetadata(null));
}
```

In the View/XAML this property is bound to the ViewModel:

```
<Grid>
  <Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
  </Grid.RowDefinitions>
  <ucc:CustomDataGrid Grid.Row="0" 
                      ItemsSource="{Binding DataGridItems}"
                      SelectionMode="Extended"
                      AlternatingRowBackground="Beige"
                      SelectionUnit="FullRow"
                      IsReadOnly="True"
                      SelectedItemsList="{Binding DataGridSelectedItems, 
                                          Mode=TwoWay,
                                          UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />

  <Button Grid.Row="1"
        Margin="5"
        HorizontalAlignment="Center"
        Content="Select some rows"
        Command="{Binding CmdSelectSomeRows}"/>

</Grid>
```

The ViewModel also implements the command CmdSelectSomeRows which selects some rows for testing. The ViewModel of the test application looks like this:

```
public class CustomDataGridViewModel : ObservableObject
{
  public IList DataGridSelectedItems
  {
    get { return dataGridSelectedItems; }
    set
    {
      dataGridSelectedItems = value;
      OnPropertyChanged(nameof(DataGridSelectedItems));
    }
  }

  public ICommand CmdSelectSomeRows { get; }

  public ObservableCollection<ExamplePersonModel> DataGridItems { get; private set; }



  public CustomDataGridViewModel()
  {
    // Create some example items
    DataGridItems = new ObservableCollection<ExamplePersonModel>();

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
      DataGridItems.Add(new ExamplePersonModel
      {
        Name = $"Test {i}",
        Age = i * 22
      });
    }

    CmdSelectSomeRows = new RelayCommand(() =>
    {
      if (DataGridSelectedItems == null)
      {
        DataGridSelectedItems = new ObservableCollection<ExamplePersonModel>();
      }
      else
      {
        DataGridSelectedItems.Clear();
      }

      DataGridSelectedItems.Add(DataGridItems[0]);
      DataGridSelectedItems.Add(DataGridItems[1]);
      DataGridSelectedItems.Add(DataGridItems[4]);
      DataGridSelectedItems.Add(DataGridItems[6]);
    }, () => true);
  }
  
  
  
  private IList dataGridSelectedItems = new ArrayList();
}
```

This works, but only partially: After application start when items are added to the SelectedItemsList from ViewModel, they are *not* displayed as selected rows in the DataGrid. To get it to work I must first select some rows with the mouse. When I then add items to the SelectedItemsList from ViewModel these *are* displayed selected – as I want it.

How can I achieve this without having to first select some rows with the mouse?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should subscribe to the Loaded event in your CustomDataGrid and initialize the SelectedItems of the Grid (since you never entered the SelectionChangedEvent, there is no link between the `SelectedItemsList` and the SelectedItems of your DataGrid.

```
private bool isSelectionInitialization = false;

    private void CustomDataGrid_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.isSelectionInitialization = true;
        foreach (var item in this.SelectedItemsList)
        {
            this.SelectedItems.Clear();
            this.SelectedItems.Add(item);
        }
        this.isSelectionInitialization = false;
    }
```

and the SelectionChanged event handler has to be modified like this:

```
private void CustomDataGrid_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!this.isSelectionInitialization)
        {
            this.SelectedItemsList = this.SelectedItems;
        }
        else
        {
            //Initialization from the ViewModel
        }
    }
```

Note that while this will fix your problem, this won't be a true synchronization as it will only copy the items from the ViewModel at the beginning.
If you need to change the items in the ViewModel at a later time and have it reflected in the selection let me know and I will edit my answer.

---

Edit: Solution to have a "true" synchronization

I created a class inheriting from DataGrid like you did.
You will need to add the using

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Specialized;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
```

```
public class CustomDataGrid : DataGrid
    {
        public CustomDataGrid()
        {
            this.SelectionChanged += CustomDataGrid_SelectionChanged;
            this.Loaded += CustomDataGrid_Loaded;
        }

        private void CustomDataGrid_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            //Can't do it in the constructor as the bound values won't be initialized
            //If it is expected for the bound collection to be null initially, you could subscribe to the change of the 
            //dependency in order to subscribe to the collectionChanged event on the first non null value
            this.SelectedItemsList.CollectionChanged += SelectedItemsList_CollectionChanged;
            //We call the update in case we have already some items in the VM collection
            this.UpdateUIWithSelectedItemsFromVm();
            
            if(this.SelectedItems.Count != 0)
            {
                //Otherwise the items won't be as visible unless you change the style (this part is not required)
                this.Focus();
            }
            else
            {
                //No focus
            }
        }

        private void SelectedItemsList_CollectionChanged(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            this.UpdateUIWithSelectedItemsFromVm();
        }

        private void UpdateUIWithSelectedItemsFromVm()
        {
            if (!this.isSelectionChangeFromUI)
            {
                this.isSelectionChangeFromViewModel = true;
                this.SelectedItems.Clear();
                if (this.SelectedItemsList == null)
                {
                    //Nothing to do, we just cleared all the selections
                }
                else
                {
                    if (this.SelectedItemsList is IList iListFromVM)
                        foreach (var item in iListFromVM)
                        {
                            this.SelectedItems.Add(item);
                        }
                }
                this.isSelectionChangeFromViewModel = false;
            }
            else
            {
                //Nothing to do, the change is coming from the SelectionChanged event
            }
        }

        private void CustomDataGrid_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            //If your collection allow suspension of notifications, it would be a good idea to add a check here in order to use it
            if(!this.isSelectionChangeFromViewModel)
            {
                this.isSelectionChangeFromUI = true;
                if (this.SelectedItemsList is IList iListFromVM)
                {
                    iListFromVM.Clear();
                    foreach (var item in SelectedItems)
                    {
                        iListFromVM.Add(item);
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    throw new InvalidOperationException("The bound collection must inherit from IList");
                }
                this.isSelectionChangeFromUI = false;
            }
            else
            {
                //Nothing to do, the change is comming from the bound collection so no need to update it
            }
        }

        private bool isSelectionChangeFromUI = false;

        private bool isSelectionChangeFromViewModel = false;

        public INotifyCollectionChanged SelectedItemsList
        {
            get { return (INotifyCollectionChanged)GetValue(SelectedItemsListProperty); }
            set { SetValue(SelectedItemsListProperty, value); }
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty SelectedItemsListProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register(nameof(SelectedItemsList),
                                        typeof(INotifyCollectionChanged),
                                        typeof(CustomDataGrid),
                                        new PropertyMetadata(null));
    }
```

You will have to initialize the `DataGridSelectedItems` earlier or you there will be a null exception when trying to subscribe to the collectionChanged event.

```
/// <summary>
/// I removed the notify property changed from your example as it probably isn't necessary unless you really intended to create a new Collection at some point instead of just clearing the items
/// (In this case you will have to adapt the code for the synchronization of CustomDataGrid so that it subscribe to the collectionChanged event of the new collection)
/// </summary>
public ObservableCollection<ExamplePersonModel> DataGridSelectedItems { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<ExamplePersonModel>();
```

I didn't try all the edge cases but this should give you a good start and I added some directions as to how to improve it. Let me know if some parts of the code aren't clear and I will try to add some comments.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! It would be great to have a true synchronization as in my case the selection should potentially be changeable from the ViewModel. How could this be done?

Comment: With your edit it now works really great. Exactly what I wanted to achieve. Many thanks for taking the time to answer and also for writing well documented code.

Comment: No problem, glad that helped :)