# Wpf MutliSelect DataGrid with custom datagrid

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I'm aware that there are several posts about how to implement datagrid mutliselection.

I've found the open issue on Github (https://github.com/dotnet/wpf/issues/3140).
The user ice1e0 mentioned a solution with a `CustomDataGrid` class.

```cs
public class CustomDataGrid : DataGrid
{
        public static readonly DependencyProperty SelectedItemsProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(nameof(SelectedItems), typeof(IList), typeof(CustomDataGrid), new PropertyMetadata(default(IList), OnSelectedItemsPropertyChanged));

        protected override void OnSelectionChanged(SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnSelectionChanged(e);
            SetValue(SelectedItemsProperty, base.SelectedItems);
        }

        public new IList SelectedItems
        {
            get => (IList)GetValue(SelectedItemsProperty);
            set => throw new Exception("This property is read-only. To bind to it you must use 'Mode=OneWayToSource'.");
        }

        private static void OnSelectedItemsPropertyChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            ((CustomDataGrid)d).OnSelectedItemsChanged((IList)e.OldValue, (IList)e.NewValue);
        }

        protected virtual void OnSelectedItemsChanged(IList oldSelectedItems, IList newSelectedItems)
        {
        }
}
```

So, I tried to implement it, so I copied the class.
And my xaml looks something like that:

```xml
<Project1:CustomDataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Data}" SelectionMode="Extended" SelectionUnit="FullRow" IsReadOnly="True" SelectedItems="{Binding SelectedComputers, Mode=OneWayToSource}" />
```

and my ViewModel:

```cs
[ObservableProperty]
ObservableCollection<string> _selectedComputers;
```

I use CommunityToolkit.Mvvm (v8.0).

It compiles but `SelectedComputers` is null, after I select one or multiple items.

**UPDATE:**

The issue seems that

```cs
        void CustomDataGrid_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            this.SelectedItemsList = this.SelectedItems;
        }
```

doesn't work. `SelectedItemsList` is always null. The problem is mentioned in the other thread: [Select multiple items from a DataGrid in an MVVM WPF project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22868445/select-multiple-items-from-a-datagrid-in-an-mvvm-wpf-project)

The suggested solution by M463:

> this.SelectedItemsList = this.SelectedItems; did not work for me, as SelectedItemsList was always set to null. However, changing the code to foreach (var item in this.SelectedItems) { this.SelectedItemsList.Add(item); } did the trick. Please note, that this requires you to call this.SelectedItemsList.Clear(); in advance, so the items of SelectedItemsList will not get duplicated.

When I try the solution, after selected a row the application crashes with the error:

```
System.ArgumentException: 'The value "System.Data.DataRowView" is not of type "System.String" and cannot be used in this generic collection.
Parameter name: value'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot mix types.

If you `Data` is a `DataView`, `SelectedItems` cannot be bound to an `ObservableCollection<string>` because you cannot add a (selected) `DataRowView` to an `ObservableCollection<string>`.

Also, you cannot set an `ObservableCollection<string>` property to anything else than an `ObservableCollection<string>`. That's why the value in the setter of the source property comes in as `null` when you try to set it to an `IList` using `SetValue`.

If you make `SelectedComputers` an `IList`, you should see it being set from the control:

```
[ObservableProperty]
IList _selectedComputers;
```

The other option is obviously to change the type of the dependency property.