# WPF DataGrid looses focus when tabbing on last cell

Tags: wpf, datagrid

I have some buttons and a datagrid inside my window.

```
<Button>Save</Button>
<Button>Back</Button>
<DataGrid x:Name="data" ItemsSource="{Binding Scores}" />
```

When I edit the NewItemPlaceholder-row, the new item is created when changing the first value (but no new NewItemPlaceholder-row). When I edit the last value and move on with Tab-key, a new row is generated.
But the cursor moves to Save Button instead of the first cell in that new row.

How can I keep the focus on the grid?

For completeness: I am using an ObservableCollection as ItemsSource.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution here: [Customize focus behavior after a row commit through the DataGrid.RowEditEnding event](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vinsibal/archive/2009/04/14/5-more-random-gotchas-with-the-wpf-datagrid.aspx)

```
private void data_RowEditEnding_1(object sender, DataGridRowEditEndingEventArgs e) {
    if (e.EditAction == DataGridEditAction.Commit) {
        if (e.Row.Item == data.Items[data.Items.Count - 2]) {
            var rowToSelect = data.Items[data.Items.Count - 1];
            int rowIndex = data.Items.IndexOf(rowToSelect);
            this.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new DispatcherOperationCallback((param) => {
                var cell = DataGridHelper.GetCell(data, rowIndex, 0);
                cell.Focus();
                data.BeginEdit();
                return null;
            }), DispatcherPriority.Background, new object[] { null });
        }
    }
}
```

Using the GetCell and GetRow methods from here: [datagrid get cell index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6888892/datagrid-get-cell-index)

```
static class DataGridHelper {
    static public DataGridCell GetCell(DataGrid dg, int row, int column) {
        DataGridRow rowContainer = GetRow(dg, row);

        if (rowContainer != null) {
            DataGridCellsPresenter presenter = GetVisualChild<DataGridCellsPresenter>(rowContainer);

            // try to get the cell but it may possibly be virtualized
            DataGridCell cell = (DataGridCell)presenter.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(column);
            if (cell == null) {
                // now try to bring into view and retreive the cell
                dg.ScrollIntoView(rowContainer, dg.Columns[column]);
                cell = (DataGridCell)presenter.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(column);
            }
            return cell;
        }
        return null;
    }

    static public DataGridRow GetRow(DataGrid dg, int index) {
        DataGridRow row = (DataGridRow)dg.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(index);
        if (row == null) {
            // may be virtualized, bring into view and try again
            dg.ScrollIntoView(dg.Items[index]);
            row = (DataGridRow)dg.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(index);
        }
        return row;
    }

    static T GetVisualChild<T>(Visual parent) where T : Visual {
        T child = default(T);
        int numVisuals = VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(parent);
        for (int i = 0; i < numVisuals; i++) {
            Visual v = (Visual)VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(parent, i);
            child = v as T;
            if (child == null) {
                child = GetVisualChild<T>(v);
            }
            if (child != null) {
                break;
            }
        }
        return child;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Use the [KeyboardNavigation.TabNavigation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.keyboardnavigation.tabnavigation%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) attached property:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="data" 
          ItemsSource="{Binding Scores}" 
          KeyboardNavigation.TabNavigation="Cycle" />
```

Comment: Thanks that solves the losing the focus part. But now the first row gets selected instead of the last row.

Answer (score 0):

[Here is an alternative](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19847216/439024) packaged in such a way that you can enable it in the default style for `DataGrid` and apply it throughout your application.